# Wrap a mixed set of text nodes and HTML elements with JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#goals"> | <a href="#rules"> | <a href="#controls">
    <p><a name="goals"></a></p>
    <h2>Goals</h2>
    ... yada yada
```

and want it like this.

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#goals"> | <a href="#rules"> | <a href="#controls">
</div>
```

JQuery have wrapAll(), but I can only select the links so the "|" gets left outside the div.

before('div') and after('div') creates a closed element, like `<div></div>` so what to do?

I'm using

```
$('.box a[href^="#"]')
```

to select the links. They are part of a text resource file, so I cant edit anything.

Comment: Why would one want to add unclosed HTML tags?

Comment: he doesn't, but he needs to wrap some content and jQuery won't let you add the opening and closing tags separately.

Comment: how are you currently trying to "select" the desired nodes?  Please also show the markup immediately before and after the set of nodes you want wrapped.

Comment: Added how I'm selecting the links. And HTML before and after!

Comment: Maybe select everything until first <p> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given *valid* markup as input, this works:

```
// find first link - using jQuery for expedience here
var a = $('.box > a')[0];

// create new div, and insert it before the link
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'nav';
a.parentNode.insertBefore(d, a);

// for each following node, reparent it inside the div
while (a && a.tagName !== 'P') {
    var n = a.nextSibling;
    d.appendChild(a);
    a = n;
};
```

It's actually easier without jQuery, because jQuery provides no easy way to obtain the text nodes that are contained within your menu.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/HpgJV/3/

To fix your incorrect HTML input, try this:

```
$('.box a[href^="#"]').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().insertAfter(this);
});
```

which will move any text nodes that are dropped *inside* the `<a>` tags because of the invalid markup so that they're after the tag instead.